# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 3)

Tags: support, api, python, json

I am trying the following simple code to get JSON from the Stack Exchange API and it gives me the following error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 3)

Here is my script:

```
import requests
import json
url='https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true'

r = requests.get(url)

r.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

That URL is the URL of the *documentation* page, so you'll get HTML back and not JSON. You'll need to replace it with the URL next to the 'Run' button (right-click and choose Copy Link, it should start with `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3`):

[image]